# Select multiple groups with mouse drag in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When having multiple elements in draw.io, I like to group them. Then, when having multiple groups, I'd like to select them by click-dragging a selection box over them. But by doing so, every single element is selected, but not the group itself.

The only workaround I found so far is by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking every single group.

Is there anypossibility to select groups by click-dragging a selection box over them?

Comment: I think the Ctrl is the one for that so far, may be but not sure about dragging to perform this.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for dragging the selection-box.

Answer (score 1):

In mac it worked with "option" and drag.

Answer (score 0):

"Option" and drag doesn't work for me on mac (10.14.6) and chrome.
One trick I found is:

- Select the group
- On the left panel's "Style" tab, click the checkbox next to "Fill". This fills the background of the group object. Now you can click any previously "empty" space of your diagram, and drag the object as desired.

Here is a quick demo (start at 0:15): https://recordit.co/vfCe2ZmdHD